# Why doesn't the following codes cause "unchecked cast" warning?

Tags: java, unchecked-cast

I think that `(String)x` is an unchecked cast, but the compiler does not give any  warning. Why does it happen?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object x=new Object();
        String y=(String)x;
    }
```

Comment: As long as casting class is in the same hierarchy (not sibling), compiler will not complain.

Comment: Why do you think it's an unchecked cast? (It's not.)

Comment: @Radiodef  It seems that I should learn Java with much more patience. I have been keeping misunderstanding something these days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I think that `(String)x` is an unchecked cast

No, it's not. It's checked at execution time - if the cast isn't valid, it will throw an exception.

Unchecked casts are about casts that *look* like they'll do checking, but actually don't check everything you'd expect, due to type erasure. For example:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
Object mystery = strings;
List<Integer> integers = (List<Integer>) mystery;
integers.add(0); // Works
String x = strings.get(0); // Bang! Implicit cast fails
```

Here the cast of `(List<Integer>) mystery` only checks that the object `mystery` refers to is a `List` - not a `List<Integer>`. The `Integer` part is *not* checked, because there's no such concept as a `List<Integer>` at execution time.

So in our example, that cast succeeds where it wouldn't with "real" checking - and the `add` call works fine, because that's just populating an `Object[]` with an `Integer` element. The last line fails because the call to `get()` implicitly performs a cast.

As far as the VM is concerned, the example code is *effectively*:

```
List strings = new ArrayList();
Object mystery = strings;
List integers = (List) mystery;
integers.add(0);
String x = (String) strings.get(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Java compiler gives unchecked cast warnings only for generic types